# VersionOne - does the new query.v1 support extracting attachments?

Tags: c#, rest, versionone

VersionOne  - does the new query.v1 support  extracting attachments?
If so, could someone provide an example?

This query.v1 just came in in VersionOne Summer 2013 (version 13.2)

https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
from: Attachment
select:
  - Name
  - ContentType
  - Content
```

The Blob field (Content) is returned as Base64

```
[
  [
    {
      "_oid": "Attachment:1783",
      "Name": "Attachment A",
      "ContentType": "text/plain",
      "Content": "VGhpcyBpcyB ...base64 encoded bytes here... hdHRhY2htZW50"
    }
  ]
]
```